# Decode utf8 character on javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a badly configured third party service that outputs strings like this:

```
"SK Uni=C4=8Dov vs Prostejov"
```

I want to replace on the fly all the wrong characters it sends me, so my modules work with the correctly decoded string

I have found on this website (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+010D) that the `=C4=8D` substring corresponds to the utf-8 character `č`

```
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+010D

č
...
UTF-8 Encoding:     0xC4 0x8D
UTF-16 Encoding:    0x010D
UTF-32 Encoding:    0x0000010D
...
```

but I cannot find the way to decode it automatically.

I've tried with:

```
>> String.fromCodePoint(0xc48d)
"쒍"


>> String.fromCodePoint("0xc4 0x8d")
RangeError    

>> String.fromCharCode(0xc48d)
"쒍"

etc...
```

If I do it with the utf-16 code, `String.fromCodePoint(0x010D)` outputs the correct character.

How can I make it work with utf-8 instead of utf-16 codes?

Should I convert my string to utf16 achieve what I want? If so, How can I convert it?

Comment: This reminds me of RFC 2047 and quoted printable encoding. https://dogmamix.com/MimeHeadersDecoder/

Comment: Yep, you are right @Álvaro González, treating it as a quoted printable solves it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the encoding is almost identical to percent escapes used in URLs, you can simply use:

```
decodeURIComponent("SK Uni=C4=8Dov vs Prostejov".replace(/=/g, "%"))
```